# Instanciando uma WebView

Tags: java, android, android-studio, webview

Tenho um simples aplicativo que com um determinado link retorna um html da página. 
Estou fazendo isso com uma WebView, está funcionando normalmente, todavia não quero que o usuário veja a WebView na tela do celular.

Antes estava fazendo assim para instancia-la:

```
WebView wv = findViewById(R.id.webview);
```

Então, pesquisei na net e encontrei esse jeito aqui, para instanciar sem a necessidade de criar ter a WebView na tela:

```
    final WebView wv = new WebView(this);
    setContentView(wv);
```

Porém o resultado foi o oposto, mesmo deletando a WebView no xml quando fui rodar o aplicativo, estava lá a WebView na tela, e ainda mais ocupando todo o espaço. Queria uma maneira de instancia a WebView sem que aparecesse na tela a mesma, já que o objetivo é apenas pegar o html da página e não mostrar o site para o usuário.

Comment: Há outras formas de pegar o HTML da página sem usar um webview. Você quer o HTML para algum objetivo específico?

Comment: Infelizmente não, estou fazendo scraping de uma página acadêmica, o único problema é a webView na tela. Eu poderia ocultar ele, mas ela vai continuar na tela, queria algo que não entrasse no mundo das gambiarras.

Comment: Se for só scraping, vc pode usar bibliotecas mais específicas como [jsoup](https://jsoup.org/), [Jaunt](http://jaunt-api.com/), entre outras.

Comment: Estou usando Jsoup, todavia como disse precisa fazer o login, tentei fazer o login via post pelo Jsoup (em sites como github deu certo), porém no site que estou fazendo scraping não estou conseguindo, por isso estou instanciando uma webView para recuperar o html.